# Removing the output of a command in BASH when command uses EOF variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

As part of my bash shell script I am running the following code:

```
sql -umyuser mydb <<-EOSQL 
MODIFY $MYTABLECLEAR TO TRUNCATED;\g
EOSQL
```

This works perfectly, but I get output in the terminal window, that I would like to avoid. Normally I would simply add a `>/dev/null` statement to the end of a command that I wanted to suppress output on, however I can't do this without screwing up the `EOSQL` text block.

I have tried putting the following:

```
`sql -umyuser mydb <<-EOSQL 
MODIFY $MYTABLECLEAR TO TRUNCATED;\g
EOSQL` >/dev/null
```

But here I get a message in the terminal window saying `TERMINAL: command not found`.

Interestingly the sql command still runs despite this message.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing it with parenthesis? `(sql ... ) &> /dev/null`

Comment: Your attempted workaround tries to run the output from `sql` as a shell command. Whatever or whoever convinced you to use that particular syntax should probably be abandoned as a source for shell scripting advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281908/removing-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash-when-command-uses-eof-variable/48282171?noredirect=1#comment83554318_48282171), you may use the curly braces to avoid the wastage that occurred in the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48282171/revisions) answers.

```
{sql -umyuser mydb <<-EOSQL 
MODIFY $MYTABLECLEAR TO TRUNCATED;\g
EOSQL
} &>/dev/null
# Well, this is a bit neat too, isn't it?
```

Looks all good now <kbd>:-)</kbd> courtesy  [@ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti)

Comment: The first unnecessarily buffers the output in memory; the second unnecessarily forks a new process.

Comment: Ah, sjsam, you've fallen into the [XyProblem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) trap! :-)  You've answered "how do I make this workaround work" rather than "how do I fix my underlying problem"! Kudos for pointing to the other answer.

Comment: @ghoti : Indeed, seeing the heredoc, i never thought it would be possible to use the redirection operator anywhere after that. But as you pointed out in the other answer, it could've been  used before the heredoc at least.  Aww. Oh my ;-)

Comment: Actually, you could just use curly braces instead of parentheses. Check the man page for your shell, but at least on my systems, redirections work on command lists surrounded by `{ .. }`, which are executed in the current shell rather than a subshell, thus avoiding the "wastage". (The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_01) docs aren't as explicit as the man pages on the systems I use.) [See tests here.](https://ideone.com/HDpjlR)

Answer (score 7):

Just add the output redirection immediately after the here-document redirection; the here document itself doesn't begin until the next line.

```
sql -umyuser mydb <<-EOSQL > /dev/null
MODIFY $MYTABLECLEAR TO TRUNCATED;\g
EOSQL
```

As a mnemonic, you might (mis)parse `<<-EOSQL` as `< <-EOSQL`, in which case a filename starting with `<` or `<-` indicates an "in-script" file for redirection instead of a regular named disk file. Understand, though, that `<<` and `<<-` really are separate operators from `<`. Either way, the here-doc operator can be mixed with the other redirection operators as desired as the comments are pointing out.

Comment: Might also be worthwhile to mention that it doesn't matter in what order redirections are provided. `sql -umyuser mydb >/dev/null <<-EOSQL` should work just as well, and might reduce confusion.

Comment: If you need to suppress error output as well as standard output, you can use `<<-EOSQL >/dev/null 2>&1`. Note that `>/dev/null` must come before `2>&1`, but `<<-EOSQL` can be anywhere in the sequence.

Comment: @sjsam With the switch to `{...}`, I have no problem with yours remaining the accepted answer. Mine might be less correct, but your looks less "surprising", even to me :)